# Is there any way to stop code from taking in all answers at once and inputting them all instead of taking in one specific question

Tags: python

I was working on a small quiz recently and I have been trying to figure out why it inputs one answer and tries to answer all the questions with one answer I have been trying to figure this out for 2 to 3 days now, sorry if there is a simple solution I am a new coder
TLDR; code takes one answer and tries to solve all questions

```
import random
score = 0
n = ["What is the capital of Arizona: ", "What thing in Arizona is a part of the 7 natural wonders of the world (ABRIVEATE ANSWER TO THE 1ST LETTER OF EACH WORD):  ", "what is the timezone in Arizona: "]

i = 0
answer = input(random.choice(n))
while (i < 3):
  if [0]:
    if answer == "Phoenix" or "phoenix":
      print("Correct")
      score += 1
      print(score)
    else:
        print("incorrect")

  if  [1]:
    if answer == "TGC" or "TGC":
      print("Correct")
      score += 1
      print(score)
    else:
      print("incorrect")
 
  if  [2]:
    if answer == "GMT":
      print("Correct")
      score += 1
      print(score)
    else:
      print("incorrect")
  i += 1
```

Comment: What do you think `if [0]:` does?

Comment: You only ask for input once, then go into a while loop, plus your if syntax is wrong.  Read a good Python tutorial.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true regarding `if answer == "Phoenix" or "phoenix":`

Comment: You're asking a random question. How is the rest of the code supposed to know which question you asked so that it can check the correct answer?

Comment: I suggest adding `print()` statements to your code so that you can better understand what it does. To start, these can be as simple as `print("starting while loop")` or similar messages. For more suggestions about how to do this, check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does \`a == x or y or z\` always evaluate to True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare your original to the below.

**Note:** I tried to change as little as possible and I'm not saying this is *how* to do it but to pass back your code with the minimum changed.  It assumes you would like to ask all questions (I may have got that incorrect!).

```
import random

# track score
score = 0

# keep a list of which questions have been asked already
asked = []

# list of questions
n = ["What is the capital of Arizona: ", "What thing in Arizona is a part of the 7 natural wonders of the world (ABBREVIATE ANSWER TO THE 1ST LETTER OF EACH WORD):  ", "what is the timezone in Arizona: "]

# loop while there are unasked questions
while len(asked) < len(n):
    
    # set initial choice of 0,1,2 (same as positions in n)
    choice = random.randint(0,2)
    
    # if the choice has already been asked loop
    while choice in asked:
        choice = random.randint(0,2)

    # add the valid choice to the asked list so the question in that position doesn't get asked again
    asked.append(choice)

    # ask the question from the list n, index position 'choice'
    answer = input(n[choice])

    if choice == 0:
        if answer.lower() == "phoenix":
            print("Correct")
            score += 1
            print(score)
        else:
            print("incorrect")

    # note the 'elif' which (for reading at least) makes the code less prone to errors
    elif choice == 1:
        # note the '.lower()' so you don't need Tgc or TGc or TGC or tgC or ...you get it :o)
        if answer.lower() == 'tgc':
            print("Correct")
            score += 1
            print(score)
        else:
            print("incorrect")

    elif choice == 2:
        if answer.lower() == "gmt":
            print("Correct")
            score += 1
            print(score)
        else:
            print("incorrect")

# print the user's score starting with a couple of line returns for separation
print('\n\nYou scored {score} points for 3 questions!'.format(score=score))
```

**Example:**

```
What thing in Arizona is a part of the 7 natural wonders of the world (ABBREVIATE ANSWER TO THE 1ST LETTER OF EACH WORD):  TgC
Correct
1
what is the timezone in Arizona: gMt
Correct
2
What is the capital of Arizona: A
incorrect


You scored 2 points for 3 questions!
```